# Angular | Start Test Server with Production Environment Variables

Tags: angular, npm, environment-variables

Im developing an Angular 6 application using CLI 6.0.5.

I have two files with environment variables:

`environments.ts` and `environments.prod.ts`.

When I build for production (`ng run build --prod`), the production variables are used. Running test server (`npm start`) uses test variables.

**Question:** How can I run test server with production variables?

Comment: Are you using Angular CLI? Version of the CLI?

Comment: Why would you do that ? You're supposed to mock your variables.

Comment: @MartinoBordin CLI 6.0.5

Comment: @trichetriche So I can test production backend on the client build on local host

Comment: Oh, you're not asking for unit testing, but for a development environment ! sorry, my bad on this one.

Comment: You could try: `npm start --configuration=production` (-c will also work)

Comment: @MikeBovenlander only in Angular 6, for < 5 it's `--env`

Comment: @trichetriche good to know but the question strats with: "Im developing an **Angular 6** application using CLI 6.0.5."

Comment: @MikeBovenlander agreed, but since most people don't know that there's a difference, I thought we should point this out !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are meddling your commands a little. Let's recap :

```
npm start
```

Runs the `start` command declared in your `package.json`

```
ng run build --prod
```

Doesn't exist (that I know of). It's either `ng build --prod` or `npm run build -- --prod`

Now, if you want to use different environments, the command is

```
ng serve --env prod 
ng serve --configuration prod
```

The former is for Angular < 5, the latter is for Angular 6.

To be sure that you run the good command, simply run

```
ng serve --prod
```

This will run in production mode, which can be set up in your `angular[-cli].json` file.

You of course have to declare those environments/configuration in your `angular[-cli].json` file.

Answer (score 1):

You can change environment using `--prod` option while running it with angular cli.
[This](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/serve) is the link for its doc you can refer for more options.

```
ng serve --prod
```

Happy Coding!!